# TextFileの区切り

Tags: vb.net

フォルダの中に、ファイルを読み込んでから、LISTVIEW を表示したいですが、
同じ行内の複数のデリミタで文字列の区切があります。
2016/05/15 21:59:13,739 [7] INFO - Login.User_Aut - o03dx1n Unknown - Login: KST028

```
     Day        2016/05/15
     Time       21:59:13,739
     LogType    [7] INFO
     MethodName Login.User_Aut
     SessionID  o03dx1n Unknown
     LoginID    Login: KST028
```

Message 
下に Split にスペースを入りましたが、日付と時間,LogType だけ区切りできました。他のものが全部間違った項目が入りました。
どうすれば区切りできますか？
お教えてください。お願いします。

```
      'ファイルを読み込む
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim filepath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim inputstream As New IO.StreamReader(filepath)
        Dim newstr(2) As String
        Dim Day As Integer
        Dim Time As String
        Dim LogType As String
        Dim LoginID As String
        Dim Message As String
        Do While inputstream.Peek <> -1
        '区切り
        newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split(" ")

        Day = newstr(0)
        Time = newstr(1)
        LogType = newstr(2) & " " & newstr(3)
        LoginID = newstr(6)
        Message = newstr(7)

        '選択されたファイルを読み取り
        Me.LogListView.Items.Add(Day)
        Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Time)
        Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(LogType)    
        Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Message)
    Loop

    inputstream.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: 「どうすれば区切りできますか？」とのことですが、ファイル形式は質問者さんしか知り得ない情報です。仕様を明確にして提示してください。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: [マルチポスト](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44837552/4315484)で、質問者がこちらのスレッドは参照する意思を示していないため

Comment: @may may さん 編集をロールバックしました。質問の内容を削除してしまうような編集は控えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

読み取るファイル形式は、質問の3行目に記述されている下記の形式だと仮定して回答します。

> 2016/05/15 21:59:13,739 [7] INFO - Login.User_Aut - o03dx1n Unknown - Login: KST028

`newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split(" ")`直下に下記のコードを入れると、Splitの結果、配列のインデックスごとに何の値が入っているのかが分かります。

**Splitの結果確認用コード**

```
'区切り
newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split(" ")
'ここから追加するコード
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For i = 0 To newstr.Length - 1
    sb.AppendFormat("{0,2}: {1}", i, newstr(i)).AppendLine()
Next
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
```

**Splitの結果確認用コード実行結果**

```
 0: 2016/05/15
 1: 21:59:13,739
 2: [7]
 3: INFO
 4: -
 5: Login.User_Aut
 6: -
 7: o03dx1n
 8: Unknown
 9: -
10: Login:
11: KST028
```

上記の実行結果は、例えば`newstr(0)`の値には`2016/05/15`が、`newstr(4)`の値には`-`が入っていることを示します。
提示されたコードでは`LogType`以降のインデックスがずれてしまっていることが分かります。

半角スペースでSplitするとすべての半角スペースで区切った結果を配列化します。
そのため`MethodName = newstr(5)`などのようにファイル形式に応じて配列のインデックスを書き換える必要があります。

Comment: 回答を改修のヒント程度に留めましたが、[マルチポスト](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846433)先の本家SOの回答が模範解答だと思います。こちらのコードは考え方の参考程度にご利用ください。