# 改行の文字列を結合する方法？

Tags: vb.net

現在、visual basic を勉強しています。質問があります。

ファイルにある文字列：

```
　 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　001 aaa 2017-12-04
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　002 bbbb 2017-12-05 SendOrderData: 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 ReceiveString
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　003 ccccc 2016-09-05 Test order 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　is accepted.
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　004 dddd 2025-09-09
```

今下のイメージになってほしいです。
[image: 期待するイメージ]

以前に Split(" ")を使って文字の区切りしました。メッセージを改行されましたので、読み込むとき例外が出ました。今度、改行されたメッセージが詰めてほしいです。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 質問者は[マルチポスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36064/4236)のまま放置します。またファイル形式の詳細を求めるコメントを放置したまま質問を繰り返しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextFieldParser`や`TextReader`を使用して行単位で処理をしているのであれば、単に

```
// Forステートメント等で行を解析してフィールドの値を得る

If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(id) Then

    // 直前のデータを変更する処理
    previous.Message += " " + message
    Continue For

End If

// 新しい行の処理
```

のように前方のフィールドの内容で行を追加するか、直前のデータに追記するか判断すればよいです。

あるいはテキスト全体を置換するのであれば、

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n\t\t\t", " ") // TSVファイルの場合
```

のように正規表現で`"\r\n"`と行の区切り記号を置換してやればよいと思います。